# Shell script numbering lines in a file

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I need to find a faster way to number lines in a file in a specific way using tools like awk and sed.  I need the first character on each line to be numbered in this fashion: 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3 etc.

For example, if the input was this:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
```

The output needs to look like this:

```
1line 1
2line 2
3line 3
1line 4
2line 5
3line 6
1line 7
```

Here is a chunk of what I have.  $lines is the number of lines in the data file divided by 3.  So for a file of 21000 lines I process this loop 7000 times.

```
export i=0
while [ $i -le $lines ]
do
    export start=`expr $i \* 3 + 1`
    export end=`expr $start + 2`
    awk NR==$start,NR==$end $1 | awk '{printf("%d%s\n", NR,$0)}' >> data.out
    export i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

Basically this grabs 3 lines at a time, numbers them, and adds to an output file.  It's slow...and then some!  I don't know of another, faster, way to do this...any thoughts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's slow because you are reading the same lines over and over.  Also, you are starting up an `awk` process only to shut it down and start another one.  Better to do the whole thing in one shot:

```
awk '{print ((NR-1)%3)+1 $0}' $1 > data.out
```

If you prefer to have a space after the number:

```
awk '{print ((NR-1)%3)+1, $0}' $1 > data.out
```

Answer (score 17):

Try the `nl` command.

See https://linux.die.net/man/1/nl (or another link to the documentation that comes up when you Google for "man nl" or the text version that comes up when you run `man nl` at a shell prompt).

> The nl utility reads lines from the
>   named file or the standard input if
>   the file argument is ommitted, applies
>   a configurable line numbering filter
>   operation and writes the result to the
>   standard output.

**edit:** No, that's wrong, my apologies.  The `nl` command doesn't have an option for restarting the numbering every `n` lines, it only has an option for restarting the numbering after it finds a pattern.  I'll make this answer a community wiki answer because it might help someone to know about `nl`.

Comment: Love the Unix tools attempt at an answer in a scripting question. There is also "cat -n" as a less polished nl. And for the reflective student of sed, the following can be modified to get the exact answer desired: http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#cat-_002dn

Comment: @jaredor you should add that as an answer!

Comment: The rt.com link has become stale.

Answer (score 2):

Perl comes to mind:

```
perl -pe '$_ = (($.-1)%3)+1 . $_'
```

should work. No doubt there is an awk equivalent. Basically, `((line# - 1) MOD 3) + 1`.

Comment: perl -e 'printf "%d%s", (($.-1)%3)+1, $_'    :-D

Comment: Jonathan: Why use printf?  Seems like derobert's answer is more straightforward.

Comment: Because using printf() doesn't modify $_; there might even be a time saving, though it is unlikely to be sufficient to worry about.

Comment: If you want optimization, print will probably be faster than printf.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
 sed 's/^/1/;n;s/^/2/;n;s/^/3/' input
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is just to use grep and match everything. For example this will enumerate files:

```
grep -n '.*' <<< `ls -1`
```

Output will be:

```
1:file.a
2:file.b
3:file.c
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{printf "%d%s\n", ((NR-1) % 3) + 1, $0;}' "$@"
```

Answer (score 1):

Python

```
import sys
for count, line in enumerate(sys.stdin):
    stdout.write( "%d%s" % ( 1+(count % 3), line )
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to leave bash for this:

```
i=0; while read; do echo "$((i++ % 3 + 1)) $REPLY"; done < input
```

Comment: This will not work in case the input ever contains leading space or backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the problem. $_ will print the whole line.

```
awk '{print ((NR-1)%3+1) $_}' < input
1line 1
2line 2
3line 3
1line 4
2line 5
3line 6
1line 7

# cat input 
  line 1
  line 2
  line 3
  line 4
  line 5
  line 6
  line 7
```